# How to update composite type model in Prisma?

Tags: prisma

I am trying to implement updation in a composite-type model in Prisma.

Here is my data structure:

```
{
  "name":"toy",
  "data":{
     "sports":{
        "currentState":"false"
    },
     "business":{
        "currentState":"false"
    }
  }
   
}
```

Here I my code for updating:

```
const updatedSource = await prisma.sources.update({
            where: {
                name: 'toy'
            },
            data: {
                data: {
                    sports: {
                        currentState: "true"
                    }
                }
            },
        })
```

Here is my schema file

```
type SourcesData {
  business      SourcesDataState
  sports        SourcesDataState
}

type SourcesDataState {
  currentState StateData[]
}

type StateData {
  title String
  url   String
}

model sources {
  id           String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  data         SourcesData
  name         String   @unique
}
```

When I execute the above logic I get error as:`` Unknown arg `sports` in data.data.sports for type SourcesDataUpdateEnvelopeInput. Did you mean `set`? Available args: ``

Please guide what I am missing while updating.

Comment: Can you add your schema file in the question?

Comment: @Nurul Sundarani, I have added the schema file

Answer (score -1):

The TypeScript should be pretty helpful in telling you what arguments you can or cannot use when interacting with Prisma. I strongly recommend using a code editor that includes TypeScript typehinting/Intellisense so you can see errors and warnings about your TypeScript usage as you are developing with Prisma.

Where it says `Available args` in your error, that should tell you the arguments that `prisma.sports.update` actually expects. If I had to guess (this may not be accurate, but you HAVE to look at the TypeScript to know exactly what it's supposed to be), it should look something like this:

```js
const updatedSource = await prisma.sources.update({
    where: {
        name: 'toy'
    },
    data: {
        data: {
            update: {
                sports: {
                    update: {
                        currentState: {
                            set: ["true"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
})
```

I strongly recommend reading Prisma's documentation on updating related/nested records: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#update-a-specific-related-record

Answer (score -1):

```
let typeEncounter = await prisma.encounter.update({
    where: {
        id
    },
    data: {
        [property]: {
            update: {
                [subProperty] : value,
            },
        },
    },
    }
)
```

I get a receive the error Unknown arg `update` in data..update

I have seen some people mention nesting updates but no official documentation and can't seem to get this straightened out. Anybody have any ideas? The property and subproperty are largely irrelevant here, just examples. The code works fine aside from updated a subfield of a type (mongoDB prisma). Without the update the entire type gets overwritten rather than the selected field.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question asked by the OP, but rather as a separate question. I would recommend to treat it accordingly and ask a new question instead of answering an existing one.